# Counter-examples to the Integral Limit Theorem if you only assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ point wise.

Tags: real-analysis

This is the theorem I have.

**Integral Limit Theorem**

Assume that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and that each $f_n$ is integrable. Then, $f$ is integrable and
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b}f_n = \int_{a}^{b}f$

What are some counter-examples to the Integral Limit Theorem if you only assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise? I honestly do not have any possible solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: You could have, for example, a discontinuous function $f_n(x)$ that integrates to 1 over $[0,1]$ for all $n$ (due to a vertical asymptote at 0) but such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)= 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.  You can get similar examples with continuous functions that have large "bumps" near zero.

Comment: Let $f_n$ be a rectangle of width $1/n$ and height $n$, then $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$, but $f \to 0$ point wise.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some choices for what is actually a big topic and attracted much attention during the 19th century.

Let us restrict to just the Riemann integral on an interval  $[a,b]$.  We are skipping over examples for the improper Riemann integral (unbounded functions).  We dare not enter into the world of the Lebesgue integral where this problem truly belongs (not yet anyway).

*So I won't give you any examples.  But I will tell what examples we want.*

A.   If  $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converges pointwise to a function $f$ it is possible that  $f$ is unbounded.

B.   If  $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous  functions that converges pointwise to a bounded function $f$ it is possible that, even though it is bounded,  $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

C.   If  $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converges pointwise to a Riemann integrable function $f$ it is possible that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \int_a^bf_n(t)\,dt $$
does not exist.

D.   If  $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous  functions that converges pointwise to a continuous  function $f$ it is possible that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \int_a^bf_n(t)\,dt $$
does exist but does not equal $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$.

Contrast this with a famous theorem of the Italian mathematician Cesare Arzelà from 1885.

> **Theorem.**    If  $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of Riemann integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$ that converges pointwise on $[a,b]$ to a Riemann
> integrable function $f$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 
>  \int_a^bf_n(t)\,dt=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt.$$

[See https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_16/dominated.pdf for a discussion.]